# what is the area of face of the cube in $m^2$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

A fly is trapped inside a hollow cube. It moves from A to C along edges of cube, taking shortest possible route. It then comes back to A again along edges, taking longest route(without going over any point more than once). If the total distance traveled is 5040 meter , what is the area of face of the cube in $m^2$ ?

Please check following drawing , you will understand about A & C

[image]

Comment: What are $A$ and $C$?

Comment: Have you made some kind of attempt at a solution?

Comment: I have updated Questions with diagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is adjacent to $C$, then the shortest path is a single edge.  The longest path visits all eight vertices, hence is seven edges long.  Together that's eight edges; if the total distance is $5040$ meters, then each edges is 630 meters long, which makes each cube's face $630^2=396900$ square meters, and the total cube surface area $2381400$ square meters.

Other cases ($A$ on the same face as $C$ but not adjacent, $A$ opposite from $C$), I leave for you to figure out.

More details as per request:
Again, for the case where $A,C$ are adjacent, the longest path is what's called a [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) for a cube graph.  In fact, there's a Hamiltonian cycle, which returns back to the starting point.  The start and end point of the Hamiltonian path are adjacent, so for this case we can take a tour of all the other vertices along the way.  For the problem as given (where $A,C$ are on the same face but not adjacent), as @Guest points out you can't visit all the edges on the return trip.

Comment: Your dam right :) can please explain bit more in details ...

Comment: Really useful thanks for help :) can i have your gmail please

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see that $6$ edges are traversed for the complete round trip. Mathematically, if $x$ is the length of each edge, then $6x=5040 m$ which implies $Area of Face=x^2=(840)^2=705600$.

Comment: If by $6$ you mean $8$, then your method is sound.